# Работа утилиты ping

Tags: ip, icmp, ping, сеть

Утилита ping отправляет icmp-пакеты на хост, кроме того в ней можна изменить некоторые поля IP-пакета - ttl, don't fragment, например.

Я так понимаю, она формирует кадр и пускает его по кабелю.

Каким образом она отправляет сырые данные в кабель ? Какие средства она использует ?

Comment: Интересует также библиотеки для сырой отправки данных, ибо писать свой драйвер для сетевой карты как-то неохото =)

Comment: Гугл в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тынц мышой](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/networking/ping.c). Обратите внимание на  функции `sendping_tail()` и `ping4()`